# SQL triggers for granting/revoking privilages

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to create triggers that will grant or revoke permissions to users in mysql 5.1?

I tried this one :

```
delimiter //

create trigger sup_tog
before update on members
for each row begin
if old.fname = "xyz" and new.status = "b"
then
revoke select, update on mkdb.* from xyz;
end if;

end//
```

The error message that I got is:

> Error Code: 1422. Explicit or implicit
>   commit is not allowed in stored
>   function or trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate the rights tables in the `mysql` database directly.

table `mysql.user` holds universal rights for users (access rights to all databases)
table `mysql.db` holds access rights per database
table `mysql.table_priv`: access rights per table

Change your trigger into:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER bu_members BEFORE UPDATE ON members FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF old.fname = "xyz" AND new.status = "b" THEN BEGIN
    /*revoke select, update on mkdb.* from xyz;*/
    UPDATE mysql.db SET 
      select_priv = 'N'
      , update_priv = 'N' 
    WHERE mysql.db.user = 'xyz' AND mysql.db.db = 'mkdb';
  END; END IF;

END $$
```

Note that the changes will only take effect after the current transaction ends.
This must happen outside the trigger as @Denis has already explained.

[image] **Warning**
Beware that the structure of the `mysql` schema can change *(and has changed in the past)*.
If this happens your query may break.
`GRANT`/`REVOKE` do not have this problem.
Use this sort of code with caution and check to see if everything still works if you upgrade your MySQL server.

Comment: +1 for the warning. :-) He might manage with a stored procedure rather than a trigger.

Comment: @Denis, a stored procedure that calls `revoke` will generate the same error. Nesting will not fool the server.

Comment: Oh, OK... I thought MySQL allowed to handle transactions from within stored procedures.

Answer (score 2):

Double-check the docs on grant/revoke. The error is suggesting that they'd both be auto-committing. This cannot occur during the trigger itself, since the latter gets fired as part of an ongoing transaction.

Comment: Then is there any other way to accomplish the same in active database?

Comment: Try with a stored procedure. Unless I'm mistaking, these allow to manipulate transactions.